# Multi-tab command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, tabs

What are the best (i.e. bug free) Multi-tab command prompts in Windows?

They have them for Linux but Windows never seems to come out with one.

Comment: "but Windows never seems to come out with one."  That's because the console subsystem is a second-class citizen in Windows, at least in terms of window interaction and UX.

Comment: @afrazier I should would like to know why, it's so much more powerful than a GUI.

Comment: Here's a [thread on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950/is-there-a-better-windows-console-window/10904494#10904494)

Comment: Windows Terminal is on preview and available now. I learned about options here that seems to have more features.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check out [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font, different window styles

Comment: The issue I had with Console is that sometimes (read: Many) when minimized it wouldn't restore properly.

Comment: Didn't the OP mention "bug-free"? Last I looked Console was pretty horribly in that respect.

Comment: Yes,it's trully horribe...and all editions of this software are marked as beta.

Comment: It does not work well on my windows xp(chinese edition)

Comment: I tried to use Console2 (last release dates 2011) to run Cygwin 64 bits in my Windows 7 64 bits desktop and it didn't work. Researching a bit I was able to find [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) which is a fork of the former that is properly updated and was able to support the environment I described.

Comment: Console2 sometimes hide the last row from my view. And I can't figure out how to mark and copy in Console2!

Comment: This one is way better than Cmder which eat a lot of RAM and is slow

Comment: Can it save its state?

Answer (score 149):

Sorry for the self-promotion, I'm the author of another Console Emulator, not mentioned here.

[image]

[ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) is opensource console emulator with tabs, which represents multiple consoles and simple GUI applications as one customizable GUI window.

Initially, the program was designed to work with [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) (my favorite shell replacement - file and archive management, command history and completion, powerful editor). But ConEmu can be used with any other console application or simple GUI tools (like PuTTY for example). ConEmu is a live project, open to suggestions.

A brief excerpt from the long list of options:

- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Smooth resize, maximized and fullscreen window modes
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color
- Quake/Tilda style
- Change cursor position in command prompt (cmd, powershell) with mouse click (build 120618+)
- Works on Chinese editions of Windows :)

Far Manager users will acquire shell style drag-n-drop, thumbnails and tiles in panles, tabs for editors and viewers, true colors and font styles (italic/bold/underline).

Try it. You may read some comments on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560).

Comment: Does it provide reverse history search like in Linux console ?

Comment: What do you mean by "history"? Console output? Current version allows searching only in visible part of screen. Searching in whole buffer (scrollable area) is in plans.

Comment: no I mean on Linux you could press CNTRL + R and type a command. It will search in the history of previously executed command and provide suggestion. It pretty handy to execute long command with few keys.

Comment: Refer to windows console hotkeys. F7 or F3 for example. This is standard for windows. ConEmu has no need to override them. Alternatively, there are tcc/le, clink and Far Manager.

Comment: @VihaanVerma the `<Ctrl-R>` option you are talking about refers to bash and GNU readline. The terminal emulator, like `ConEmu` or `xterm`, shouldn't affect its operation. `<Ctrl-R>` is totally separate and unrelated to this.

Comment: Norton flags this is as "Suspicious.Cloud.7.EP".

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - False report

Comment: @Maximus You mean false positive?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Yes.

Comment: Awesome tool! I wanted to up vote but then found out I already up voted long back in the past :) Wish I could cast 2 up votes here.

Comment: The best of the conhost replacements!

Comment: Top answer! I love this tool! Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: Great tool! The split view is perfect (wish it was a bit easier to configure), but great for my needs

Comment: The tool show `user.name@pc_name` before the folder. Can I remove that? And for rename a consola the shortcut say `Apps-R` I now windows key but which one is Apps?

Comment: Look in `cmdinit.cmd`. https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html

Comment: conemu is a nightmare to configure. I am one of the first people to ever use it before anyone even hear of it and there are some simple things I can never configure to this day like changing startup dir. I would choose it with caution

Comment: Can you add the binary version in zip version instead of 7zip. Many organizations won't allow to download 7zip or .exe file.

Answer (score 16):

I realize this is 6 years after you posted the question. I've found PowerShell ISE to be an elegant solution.

There's a slight 2 second delay to start it up, but it's incredibly powerful and suitable as a tabbed command prompt in a Windows 7/8/10 environment.

It has a cleaner UI than many of the alternatives listed above, and it's built for PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks, PowerISO is pretty when you have nothing else. I just realized that I needed split view more than multi-tab, so I prefer ConEmu.

Comment: agree .. dont know why windows doesn't make it default

Comment: This is the best option amongst all. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[PromptPal](http://www.promptpal.com/) is the best I have ever used.

Comment: eh..it's not free...

Comment: Dislike it since it is not free :(

Comment: "What are the best (i.e. bug free) Multi-tab command prompts in Windows?"   That is the question that was posed.  WHERE do the downvoters see the word FREE?

Answer (score 7):

I think PowerCmd is a nice multitab cmd prompt software as well. It is **shareware**  and has all the features I expected.

You can get it from http://www.powercmd.com/
[image]

Comment: That looks pretty cool xiao.  I'll have to check that out.  Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: It's not free! It's a shareware. where did you get a free version?

Comment: I just wanted to note that I have been using PowerCMD for a year and it is extremely buggy. A lot of interactive programs like irb, p4, php etc do not run properly and cause you to have to close out. It also constantly spits out the system environment variables. It's very annoying and I am uninstalling as I type this.

Comment: He asked for BUG free.  Not necessarily MONEY free.......

Comment: I confirm this is the easiest to install and quickest to get you started (tested console and conemu but either they don't ahve installer and second needs extra setup before the can run)

Comment: Doesn't work with python interactive shell.

Answer (score 6):

What about [cmder](http://cmder.net/)? It seems to be very popular.

Comment: what does cmder do? how's it a good option? What's it do better than these alternatives?

Comment: It has a option to enable quake 3 style slidedown.

Comment: Cmder is based on ComEmu which the interface is better.

Answer (score 6):

Windows Terminal and Windows Terminal Preview are distributed by Microsoft, so they are really worth mentioning.

For Windows Terminal or Windows Terminal Preview:

1. Open Windows Store
2. Search for Windows Terminal, or for Windows Terminal Preview
3. Install

For me, the installation didn't work (I think because my pc is not connected to a Microsoft account), so I went to Microsoft's Github and installed the lastest release from an `.msi`:

1. Go to https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases
2. Download the latest release's `.msi`
3. Click it to install

Bonus - Add to Context Menu:

If you want to add Windows Terminal or Windows Terminal Preview to the context menu, use the PowerShell script linked in [this StackOverflow great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663024/3002584).

Comment: `winget install Microsoft.WindowsTerminal` This is the successor of the old `Console` app.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation (favorite commands is a killer feature):

**[ColorConsole](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/ColorConsole)**

Features:

- Favorites commands
- Export to HTML and RTF
- Copy,Paste,Cut...
- Customizable font style and color
- **Tabbed working with multi cmd.exe.**
- Fast folder switch.
- Portable

[image]

Comment: @Molly Exporting as HTML!  That is a sweet feature!

Comment: I'm going to have to give that a try.

Comment: Not really good: 1) TAB key autocompletion doesn't work anymore (it works with Windows 7's `cmd.exe`)  2) Try BACKSPACE key: it will even erase the prompt `C:\Windows>` etc.  I didn't go further but it seems that there's lot of little UI oddities.

Comment: holy shmoly nothing beats this!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/): it is a bash command prompt for Windows packaged in a multi-tab terminal with a lot of extra features (SSH, macros, bookmarks and much more).

Answer (score 4):

Windows native tab support will be released hopefully with 2018 fall Windows update.

[Tabbed console support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/04/13/tabbed-console-starts-here/)

Comment: This hasn't appeared to ship yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I recent but very mature already entrant to the Windows Consoles arena is Babun https://github.com/babun/babun 
It works similar to what you would find in a Bash-based console on a *nux machine but on any Windows OS, as a big plus all the familiar tools as ls, find, grep and more are there.

Comment: While this looks like a good tool, the question asked specifically about a multi-tab command prompt. It doesn't look like Babun supports tabs. I downvoted this answer as it does not answer the question. I'd be happy to remove my downvote if Babun does in fact support tabs.

Comment: This project is also discontinued!