# What solutions are there for getting tabbed shell windows on Win32?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-tab command prompt in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/30733/multi-tab-command-prompt-in-windows)

As the questions says, i'd like my command shell to have tabs. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread at SuperUser:
[Multi-tab command prompt in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/30733/multi-tab-command-prompt-in-windows)
Also, I think we should move this thread to SuperUser.

Comment: I think this is sort of important to developers so should at least be left here to point at that question on SuperUser.