# Using console emulator with XAMPP?

Tags: console, cmd.exe, xampp

I was recently browsing for a multi-tab console emulator, and I came across Console (via the accepted answer) here:

[Multi-tab command prompt in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/30733/multi-tab-command-prompt-in-windows)

However, I want to use Console instead of the normal command prompt when clicking on shell from the XAMPP control panel, is this possible?

Comment: Switch to ConEmu. And may be take a look at OpenServer (WAMPP)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer [How to change the default Windows terminal](https://superuser.com/a/509710/139371).

There is also handy WAMP platform [OpenServer](http://open-server.ru/download/). However I can't find English page of that package from my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I want to use Console instead of the normal command prompt when clicking on shell from the XAMPP control panel, is this possible?

This feature is not integrated in the XAMPP Control Panel, see it's source: http://sourceforge.net/p/xampp/code/HEAD/tree/win32/xampp/src/xampp-control-panel/

--

Shameless plug:

The feature you are looking for was integrated into [WPN-XM](http://wpn-xm.org/)s Server Control Panel.

- When ConEmu is not installed, clicking "Console" will open the normal windows command prompt.
- When ConEmu is installed, clicking "Console" will open a windows command prompt in a ConEmu tab.
- When ConEmu and Git for Windows are installed, it two tabs - a windows prompt and a git-bash prompt in splitscreen mode.

But you might configure ConEmu like you want :) It's awesome.

[image]