# why is windows 11 terminal with launch size of 256 x 80 is bigger than a command prompt at same launch size

Tags: command-line, terminal, fonts

Just updated to Win 11 and am dealing with the default terminal. I'd like to be able to use multiple tabs of command prompts (note: I use a console editor for writing my SAS code that wants a 256 x 80 console).

I have figured out how to get the terminal to default to open as a command prompt (e.g., vs. powershell). Note: for traditional command prompts I've always customized the Layout, in particular the launch size (256 x 80) and font of Lucidia Console 12pt (as well as colors). I've now set the terminal to launch at that same size and font BUT when it opens it's way bigger than an opened traditional command prompt, again, using the same layout and font. Any ideas why?

Note: I'm happy to just keep using command prompts traditionally (i.e., multiple open prompts vs tabs) if I have to, it's just that it might be cool to have tabbed command prompts (like tabbed windows explorer). TIA for any replies.

Comment: I can’t tell if your using Windows Terminal or not, so are you?

Comment: While you are setting the same font it is possible that Terminal is high DPI aware and is being scaled up while the old "command prompt" is not. https://pureinfotech.com/set-custom-scale-size-windows-11/

Comment: One thing to check: 12pt vs 12px

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot illustrating the issue?

Comment: Hi All: Sorry for late reply today; had AM conf. calls.... and *thanks* for all the replies.

Comment: Yes-iI am trying Terminal, albeit loading/defaulting to a Command Prompt. Mokubai--interesting thought, that actually may be it. gronostaj--I'll have to double check px vs. pt. And many others, again, I've changed default so a Command Prompt is what initially opens when I open Terminal.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/8gHXO5F

Comment: A 2nd screen shot (w/o my editor open in the console/command prompt)   https://imgur.com/a/8gHXO5F

Comment: 3rd screen shot, after changing Terminal to Lucidia Console 9. @gronostaj FTW!! traditional console/Command Prompt w/ Lucidia Console 12 has ea. character 12 pixels high x 7 px wide. In Terminal, fonts are "points". Can't an exact match (size-wise) between Terminal and Command Prompt... but much much better now. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: oops: https://imgur.com/a/8gHXO5F

Comment: To give an idea of my setup, see: https://imgur.com/cjoCT0O

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I was clear, @gronstaj basically *answered* my question, i.e., b/c of difference between pixals and points, I was able to get Terminal to almost exactly the same size as a console/Command Prompt.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 11, you have the option of opening CMD either inside the
classic Windows Console Host or inside the new Terminal Windows.

The default is now to open inside Terminal Windows, but this
can be changed using
*Settings > Privacy & security > For developers > Terminal*.
Setting this to Windows Console Host means that both CMD and PowerShell
will open using the old classical interface, which lacks tabs.

If you wish to have tabs for PowerShell, this means leaving this
setting as Terminal Windows, but this means that CMD opens
also in it.

To use CMD with the old interface and PowerShell with the new interface
requires a third-party product.

See this post for possibilities :
[Multi-tab command prompt in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/30733/multi-tab-command-prompt-in-windows)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: @gronostaj: In that case, offer another solution.

Comment: OP isn’t asking about how to change whether Windows Terminal or the classic console host opens. The only question is also in the title: Why is Windows Terminal larger?

Comment: Mokubai offered a theory, but that's all we can do here - theories. CMD uses old DOS commands to display while PowerShell uses others. It might be a difference in using the Windows API, or even a bug. In any case, I offered a solution to the poster's underlying problem, rather than leaving the post without an answer. I'll delete this answer if a better one comes along.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is even remotely related to any underlying problem, sorry.

Comment: @DanielB: Final problem description : "I'm happy to just keep using command prompts traditionally (i.e., multiple open prompts vs tabs) if I have to, it's just that it might be cool to have tabbed command prompts (like tabbed windows explorer).". The rest of the post describes unsuccessful attempts to achieve tabbed command prompts.